# Filter Github issues by status in connected project

Tags: github

We have a github organization with a [project feature](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/learning-about-projects/about-projects). With this feature we can show a Kanban board with issues from different repositories. In the repository I now want to filter all isues which have the status "Todo". In the Kanban view I can filter the issue by `status: Todo` but this filter doesn't work on the repository level. Here I only could figure out how to filter by the project but not by the status on the Kanban Board in the project. Does anybody found solution for that?

Comment: Did you find out? Maybe a script through the API could work.

Comment: No unfortunately not. My feeling is that it is only possible by means of some workarounds. It seems that the status is a [custom field](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/understanding-fields/renaming-custom-fields) that only exists within the project but not in the repository. I think you could write a gh action that attaches a label to the ticket that has the value of the status and then you could filter the repo by the label. But personally I think it makes more sense to wait for gh to fix this. IMO this should be possible without any technical crutches.

Comment: Yeah, all they need to do is add a "Close all tickets" button or something. I tried doing it using the API, but didn't get anywhere.